# What is wrong with these jquery statements?

Tags: jquery, function, document, ready

I'm unable to get this jquery statement to work on page load but it works once when I refresh `F5` the page.

```
<div id="ResultsDiv"></div>
<div id="pager" class="pager"></div>
<input id="HfId" type="hidden" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var itemsPerPage = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
  getRecordspage(0, itemsPerPage);
  var maxvalues = $("#HfId").val();
  alert(maxvalues);
  $(".pager").pagination(maxvalues, {
    callback: getRecordspage,
    current_page: 0,
    items_per_page: itemsPerPage,
    num_display_entries: 5,
    next_text: 'Next',
    prev_text: 'Prev',
    num_edge_entries: 1
  });
});
</script>
```

On the initial pageload `alert(maxvalues);` is nothing. However when I refresh it shows the value of `maxvalues` which is in the hidden field `HfId` because it is assigned in the function `getRecordspage`.

Why this strange behaviour.... Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**

```
function getRecordspage(curPage) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        data: "{'currentPage':" + (curPage + 1) + ",'pagesize':5}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            $("#ResultsDiv").empty();
            $("#HfId").val("");
            var strarr = jsonObj.d.split('##');
            var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(strarr[0]);
            var divs = '';
            $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
            });
    $(".pager").pagination(strarr[1], {
             callback: getRecordspage,
             current_page: 0,
             items_per_page: 5,
             num_display_entries: 5,
             next_text: 'Next',
             prev_text: 'Prev',
             num_edge_entries: 1
         });
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
            $(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
            $(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("resultshover");
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("resultshover");
            });
            $("#HfId").val(strarr[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Need to see the getRecordspage function I suspect.

Comment: Let's see getRecordspage(...)

Comment: So, what's `strarr[1]` the first time the page loads and the $.ajax(...) is executed?

Comment: @strelok `strarr[1]` is `17` when i alerted...

Comment: @sterlok look at the top of my question including the `<script>` below the hiddenfield may be the prob? I dont know plz check it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getRecordspage` function is asynchronous. It makes an Ajax call which, when it completes, sets the value you are trying to read. However, you are not waiting for the call to complete before reading the value.

Comment: @David if i include with in success function my callback function gets called over and over....

Comment: @David suggest me how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the $.ajax(...) `success` callback is being executed *after* the `alert(maxvalues);` is called. If that's indeed the case, just place your pagination code

```
$(".pager").pagination(maxvalues, {
     //my syntax
});
```

in the $.ajax(...) `success` callback.

Comment: @sterlok if i include with in success function my callback function gets called over and over...

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your problem (missing functions, etc) the best advice is to tell you to use [firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/) and install [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) and [firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/).

Then try to put some breakpoints and inspect values. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/)

EDIT : made this answer before I saw your edit with more info.